# ESRI JavaScript API Web Application and SQL Queries in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, sql, query, asp.net

My workflow (and security restrictions) for a new html/javascript based web application is making me think that I could program an ASP.NET application, inside which I load the 'map' and the 'legends' objects etc using the usual Dojo libraries.

But before I go too far with this approach, I need to know whether usual ASP.NET Sql queries would be enough to kind of feed the map all the information which typically the ESRI Javascript API based applications use. Specifically, currently:

```
http://myserver/myservice/MapServer/0/query?f=json&where=
```

could become a standard ASP.NET SQL Server query targeting the database's tables; I suspect I will need to somehow make the return as JSON output and then feed to the web application?

Am I on right track? Has anyone done something like this before? What are the pitfalls I need to be aware of?

Comment: I don't see why it isn't possible.  We use a PostGreSQL/PostGIS backend that feeds data into OpenLayers.  From what I understand (I do the ESRI side so I am not 100% sure), they're just feeding URLs and configuration settings from the DB backend that point to layers running through GeoServer.  I would it would be similar.  You should try a trial run and post your results.

Comment: Branco...Yes, that's what I am thinking too. I see no reason why the approach I have outlined shouldn't work. My approach may be a bit painstaking to put together but is almost certainly worth it. I have been working on a test-run and will post here. Thaks.

Comment: From what I understand from our open-source side of things.  They created a generic web app that will read in the data from the DB and render the webpage/data accordingly.  It is a pretty neat design that allows a write once and reuse type of project.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have been pegged back because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838609/c-sql-server-spatial-function-polygon-rings-error-on-some-records before I can program...